How to place tikzpicture next to enumerate
This is my code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% maths
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

% tikzpicture
\usepackage{tikz, scalerel, pict2e, tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, arrows.meta, shadows, external}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics, fillbetween}

% colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (4,6);
            % techo
            \fill[gray] (0, 6) rectangle (3, 5);
            \draw[line width=2pt] (0,5) -- (3,5);
            % circulo
            \fill[lightgray](2,3) circle [radius=1];
            \draw[] (2,3) circle [radius=1];        
            % cuerdas
            \draw (1,3) -- (1,5);
            \draw (2,3) -- (2,1);
            % caja
            \fill[gray] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1);
            \draw[] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1) node[midway] {\textbf{$m$}};
            % eje
            \draw[-Stealth] (3.5, 5) -- (3.5, 3) node[midway, right] {$\vec{g}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Un cilindro de masa M y radio R está dispuesto como se muestra en la figura.\\
        El cilindro cuelga del techo mediante un corón ideal que está enrollado alrededor del mismo. Desde un eje liso en el centro de la polea cuelga una masa m.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Calcule el módulo de la aceleración del centro de masa del disco.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}

This is what I want:


You might try \usepackage{wrapstuff} instead of loading wrapfig, it sort of works with lists.

Paracol is more robest, but can only break (easily) between paragraphs (items).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% maths
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

% tikzpicture
\usepackage{tikz, scalerel, pict2e, tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, arrows.meta, shadows, external}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics, fillbetween}

% colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*

\begin{document}
    \sbox1{% measure width
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (4,6);
            % techo
            \fill[gray] (0, 6) rectangle (3, 5);
            \draw[line width=2pt] (0,5) -- (3,5);
            % circulo
            \fill[lightgray](2,3) circle [radius=1];
            \draw[] (2,3) circle [radius=1];        
            % cuerdas
            \draw (1,3) -- (1,5);
            \draw (2,3) -- (2,1);
            % caja
            \fill[gray] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1);
            \draw[] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1) node[midway] {\textbf{$m$}};
            % eje
            \draw[-Stealth] (3.5, 5) -- (3.5, 3) node[midway, right] {$\vec{g}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-\wd1}% right column gets remainder
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    \switchcolumn[1]
        \box1
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Un cilindro de masa M y radio R está dispuesto como se muestra en la figura.\\
        El cilindro cuelga del techo mediante un corón ideal que está enrollado alrededor del mismo. Desde un eje liso en el centro de la polea cuelga una masa m.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Calcule el módulo de la aceleración del centro de masa del disco.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}


wrapfig and lists such as enumerate do not see eye-to-eye. The simplest approach is probably something like minipages. For example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Un cilindro de masa M y radio R está dispuesto como se muestra en la figura.\\
    El cilindro cuelga del techo mediante un corón ideal que está enrollado alrededor del mismo. Desde un eje liso en el centro de la polea cuelga una masa m.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Calcule el módulo de la aceleración del centro de masa del disco.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (4,6);
    % techo
    \fill[gray] (0, 6) rectangle (3, 5);
    \draw[line width=2pt] (0,5) -- (3,5);
    % circulo
    \fill[lightgray](2,3) circle [radius=1];
    \draw[] (2,3) circle [radius=1];
    % cuerdas
    \draw (1,3) -- (1,5);
    \draw (2,3) -- (2,1);
    % caja
    \fill[gray] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1);
    \draw[] (1.5,0.5) rectangle (2.5,1) node[midway] {\textbf{$m$}};
    % eje
    \draw[-Stealth] (3.5, 5) -- (3.5, 3) node[midway, right] {$\vec{g}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

